# PlayOnLinux Help - Error: What's the reason for this apt-get install error?

Tags: 16.04, apt, playonlinux

So I recently tried to install playonlinux on *Ubuntu 16.04* and it was installing but stopped halfway through the installation, so I closed it and that was where I messed up.
Now every time I enter

```
sudo apt-get update
```

in the terminal the error is:

```
E: Type '--2017-01-12' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list  
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu Version 16.04

Comment: Try sudo apt remove --purge {installation}, then try again.

Comment: I did this and it said:  N: Ignoring file 'playonlinux.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Type '--2017-01-12' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: What does that mean? I'm new to linux

Comment: Just delete it as L.D. said....sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list

Comment: The error is showing that you have a problem with that particular repository entry.  You didn't have to install that entry.  There is a working version of the **Playonlinux** application in the default repository that is shipped with your version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Remove, rename or disable this repository entry file:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
```

Then run these commands:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt apt autoremove
$ sudo apt install --reinstall playonlinux
```